# Cocos2d cocos builder(spritebuilder) with game center

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, game-center, spritebuilder

I would like to show UIView for game center.

```
-(void)authenticateLocalPlayer {
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error)

        else

    }];
}
- (void)didLoadFromCCB {

    [self authenticateLocalPlayer];

    _viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    GKLeaderboardViewController* leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != nil){

        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime; 
        leaderboardController.category = @"mygamehighscore";
        [_viewController presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
    }
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:_viewController.view];

}
```

but it shows this error and no game center pop up appeared.

```
Warning: Attempt to present <GKLeaderboardViewController: 0x15db51f0> on <UIViewController: 0x15db4d10> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you are invoking the method `presentViewController` on the wrong view controller (which is not in the hierarchy when the method is invoked).

There is no need to create a new UIViewController, you can use the one provided by Cocos2D (my code refers to Cocos2D-iPhone 2.0).

Try with:

```
AppController * appController = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appController.navController presentViewController: leaderboardController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: it says Property 'navController' not found on object of type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'.

Answer (score 1):

It should look like that:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
```

The complete code:

```
GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
if (leaderboardController != NULL)
{
    leaderboardController.category = kLeaderboardID;
    leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeWeek;
    leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```